# Can't find jQuery

Tags: jquery, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2015

As the image shows I've added the jQuery package to the form.

[image]

This is the latest update with the newest interface.

How ever I get the following error message.

> ReferenceError: '$' is undefined
>      at temp (https://xxxx.crm4.dynamics.com/%7B635678213980001086%7D/WebResources/xxxx_Temp.js?ver=1543403284:4:5)

The "code" not working is this.

```
function temp() { $.ajax({...}); }
```

Please note that the code for the actual rendition of HTML **is not** done as a source code that can be edited in CRM.

I've tried accessing it through the console and it seems to work other than that I'm beginner and I'm lost. Not sure which keywords to google on.

Comment: We need to see your code here. How are you including jQuery? Is your code running under the DOMReady event? Any errors in the console?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan He's a new user and can't post images. Stop downvoting so he can show the control, please. He needs at least 10 rep to show the problem.

Comment: @KonradViltersten excuse me? 1. I haven't downvoted him 2. The image is mentioned but the URL leads nowhere, and 3. I am trying to help him by telling him what information we need.

Comment: You don't need to post images to show code or errors. Please don't accuse people of downvoting when you can't see who did it.

Comment: @SterlingArcher In CRM, as the tags show, you DO need to post an image. THat's how it works. Please stop downing him. He's not a fake. Please give it a second and you'll see. It's not "jquery" only. It's different in CRM.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Sorry, I assumed you did. At any case, he **needs** to post an image to show the error. There's no code when adding jQuery to a site in CRM.

Comment: Ok, if he uploads it to a site like http://imgur.com and edits the question with a link I can add the image in for him.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan We'll do that right away. But I strongly feel that it's a bit weird (although I see where it comes from). Of course, I'm tired of people whining about source code. IN CRM you don't have that and I think that people should observe the tags more carefully.   :)

Comment: @SterlingArcher We've made a change (still showing an image, as it' ssupposed to be done in CRM). Can you kindly please remove the downvote so the guy next to me can join SO for real?

Comment: The information represented in the table pictured could just as well be represented by, say, a table.

Comment: @ssube Partly, yes. However, my experience with CRM is that sometimes (not very frequenly but often enough), an experienced used may notice something that just a table or quotation doesn't cover. An extreme example was when someone could make their DLLs work and, as they described it, it should've work. Then I saw an image - the background was **orange** and not **navy**, which made me realize that the poor dude was in a sandboxed environment (which was a new thing back then). So I've learned that **sometimes** there might be an advantage in posting an image. But you've got a good point, too.

Answer (score 3):

You are relying on a 3rd-party JQuery file, that may be your problem. I'm not sure, but Microsoft may do a `.noConflict()` in that library such that the `$` is not a reference to JQuery.

[Microsoft's documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh771584.aspx#BKMK_UsingjQuery) specifically recommends against using JQuery in form events.

> We do not recommend using jQuery in form scripts and ribbon commands.
>   Most of the benefit provided by jQuery is that it allows for easy
>   cross-browser manipulation of the DOM. This is explicitly unsupported
>   within form scripts and ribbon commands. Restrict your scripts to use
>   the Xrm.Page and Xrm.Utility libraries available in form scripts and
>   ribbon commands.

You do not need to use `$.ajax()`:

> Using $.ajax to perform requests against the OData and Modern Apps
>   SOAP endpoint is supported, but there are alternatives. The
>   alternative to using $.ajax is to use the browsers XMLHttpRequest
>   object directly. The jQuery $.ajax method is just a wrapper for this
>   object. If you use the native XMLHttpRequest object directly, you do
>   not need to load jQuery.

If you would like to avoid all the troubleshooting go with a reliable solution that has already worked out these issues and may more. I recommend looking at [XrmServiceToolkit](https://xrmservicetoolkit.codeplex.com) which includes its own copy of JQuery and is fully tested against Dynamics CRM 2015.

Regardless, you should certainly not be relying on the JQuery library that came in the Activities Feed solution.

Comment: It might be my fault. I recommended jQuery since that's what I've always used. I prefer its syntax, too. Anyway, +1 for a clear and extensive answer.

Comment: Definitely recommend it for WebResources where you have DOM manipulation...for Data calls I'm a fan of XrmServiceToolkit - it's great!

Answer (score 2):

As [MSDN itself](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1bb82714-1bd6-4ea4-8faf-93bf29cabaad#BKMK_UsingJQuery) gives examples for retrieving data through organization service by JavaScript both **with** jQuery and **without** it, it's easy to get mislead to believe that they're equally suitable.

It gets even more misleading when reading *...Using $.ajax to perform requests against the OData and Modern Apps SOAP endpoint is supported...*, if the reader stops there and doesn't invest in scrutinizing the whole paragraph.

However, it seems that Microsoft aims to discourage using jQuery (which in my view is sort of an industry standard) and push us towards XmlHttp (which IM-not-so-HO is both ugly syntactically and has a very confusing name).

That probably explains why the jQuery version that comes preinstalled on the newest organizations is 1.5, while the older ones had 1.7 since 2011.

So there are two options to handle it.

1. Install the latest jQuery manually.
2. Adapt the unwrapped approach of XmlHttp.

(1) has the advantage of being a wider solution than just-the-small-CRM-pond. It also gives more competence working with older versions and, definitely, unsupported ones. In case one needs to apply an Iframe or customize a portal integrated with CRM, jQuery is a must-know.

(2) has the advantage of being recommended by Microsoft. Poof.

Comment: To clarify, JQuery does not come "pre-installed." It is used by CRM for its own internal purposes. The SDK does not makes reference to it being available so it is not appropriate to assume it is available.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening only in the Crm 2015 online environment.

I have added version 1.7.2 from the Xrm Service Toolkit as the first library on the form and still can't get the '$' to be recognized for something simple (loading of the second library adds a css that gets used during display of a JQuery dialog popup on a change event):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("<link/>", { rel: "stylesheet", type: "text/css", href: Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/WebResources/tss_duplicatepopupcss" }).appendTo("head");
}
```